# c++ program, text constantly shaking in cmd

Tags: c++, cmd

This program is supposed to have a map made out of dots and a player which you can move around.

But when I opened this program one day, the text was flickering and moving up and down.

It uses Windows.h to redraw on the console without flickering and to hide the cursor

Does it have to do something with the cmd properties, the code or the Windows.h header file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

char map[1000][1000];
int width = 100;
int height = 10;
char Tmt = '.';

void cls()
{
    COORD cursorPosition;
    cursorPosition.X = 0;
    cursorPosition.Y = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cursorPosition);
}

void hidcur()
{
    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO info;
    info.dwSize = 100;
    info.bVisible = FALSE;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(consoleHandle, &info);
}

class Player {
public:

    int x;
    int y;
    char sym;

    void Draw()
    {
        map[x][y] = sym;
    }

    void Logic()
    {
        if (x < 1) { x++; }
        if (y < 1) { y++; }
        if (x > width) { x--; }
        if (y > height) { y--; }
    }

    void Input()
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            switch (_getch())
            {
            case 'w':
                map[x][y] = Tmt;
                y--;
                break;
            case 'a':
                map[x][y] = Tmt;
                x--;
                break;
            case 's':
                map[x][y] = Tmt;
                y++;
                break;
            case 'd':
                map[x][y] = Tmt;
                x++;
                break;
            case 'p':
                system("cls");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void PrintPos()
    {
        printf("Pos:\n");
        if (x >= 10) { printf("    %d\n", x); }
        else { printf("    0%d\n", x); }
        if (y >= 10) { printf("    %d\n", y); }
        else { printf("    0%d\n", y); }
    }
};

Player player1;

void Setup()
{
    player1.x = 2;
    player1.y = 2;
    player1.sym = '@';
    player1.Draw();
    player1.Logic();

    for (int mapsui = 1; mapsui <= width; mapsui++)
    {
        for (int mapsuj = 1; mapsuj <= height; mapsuj++)
        {
            map[mapsui][mapsuj] = Tmt;
        }
    }
}

void DrawMap()
{
    player1.PrintPos();
    printf("\n\n\n");
    for (int drawi = 1; drawi <= width; drawi++)
    {
        for (int drawj = 1; drawj <= height; drawj++)
        {
            printf("%c", map[drawj][drawi]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    Setup();

    while (1)
    {
        DrawMap();
        player1.Input();
        player1.Logic();
        player1.Draw();

        cls();
        hidcur();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DrawMap method, when you have the two for loops, you are checking width in the outer loop and height in the inner loop, while it should be the other way round. Note that the outer loop controls the number of lines, and as you are limiting it to the width (100) you are displaying 100 lines most of which are empty, because Setup just initializes 10 lines. As the command window shows less lines (I think it's about 30 by default or something like that) the map goes up and that results in the flicker you see. It should be:

```
for (int drawi = 1; drawi <= height; drawi++)
{
    for (int drawj = 1; drawj <= width; drawj++)
    {
        printf("%c", map[drawj][drawi]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note than in Setup you also use the loops in this way (the outer loop checks width and the inner loop checks height) but in that case you are later using the indexes to the map the other way round (first i and then j) so that results in the correct initialization of the map (10 rows of 100 columns).